# wrap text in SSRS Portal

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to wrap the text for the description column in the SSRS portal for SSRS 2022?

I can see where to edit the css and I see where the css is generated (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\Portal\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Web.dll) but I am not sure if there is a way to edit that.

Thanks